# FFMPEG failing to render PNGs as ProRes 4444

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a series of PNGs with transparent background that I would like to render as a video with an alpha channel. I tried running the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -i frames/%04d.png -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le video.mov
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Quicktime can't open the video and when I try to import it into DaVinci Resolve it's treated as corrupt. Is there some other parameter that I'm missing?

I'm running FFMPEG version 4.4.1. Here's the full output when I run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_4 --enable-shared 
  --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= 
  --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl 
  --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame 
  --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband 
  --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora 
  --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx 
  --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 
  --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype 
  --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex 
  --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack 
  --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Comment: Why are you posting both in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1698418/ffmpeg-failing-to-render-pngs-as-prores-4444) and here?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know which is the more appropriate forum